# JQuery, how to get attribute in loop from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I had a problem with array and loop, i want to set two attributes(yt to task and href to b b_yt) from array, for example:

```
                              //from
<div class="task" yt="">
    <div class="button">
         <a class="b b_yt" href="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="task" yt="">
    <div class="button">
         <a class="b b_yt" href="">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="task" yt="">
    <div class="button">
         <a class="b b_yt" href="">
    </div>
</div>

                              //to
<div class="task" yt="a">
    <div class="button">
         <a class="b b_yt" href="a">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="task" yt="b">
    <div class="button">
         <a class="b b_yt" href="b">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="task" yt="b">
    <div class="button">
         <a class="b b_yt" href="b">
    </div>
</div>
```

My js:

```
        var arr = ['a','b','c'];

        var allBtn = document.querySelectorAll('a.but.b_yt');
        var allDiv = document.querySelectorAll('div.task');

        allDiv.forEach(function(item, i){
            item.setAttribute('yt', arr[i]);
        });  
        //This is changing yt attribute in task and it is working
```

How to get yt attribute value from div.task and set it in href at a.but b_yt, of course in loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
allDiv.forEach(function(item, i){
            $(item).closest("task")[0].setAttribute('yt', arr[i]);
        });
```

you use closest jquery function to get the parent item with parent class name.